# Strange postgres message in heroku log

Tags: postgresql, heroku

```
[RED] restartpoint complete: wrote 3392 buffers (10.9%); 
0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 9 recycled; 
write=340.005 s, sync=0.241 s, total=340.257 s; 
sync files=86, longest=0.121 s, average=0.002 s
```

and

```
 [RED] recovery restart point at 2AA/A90FB758 Detail: last completed transaction was at log time 2015-01-21 14:00:18.782442+00
```

`RED` database is a follower of master database. What these log entries mean??

Comment: Did you ever find out what these messages mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are informational log messages telling you that the server finished creating a restart point completed.  There should be other messages telling that the server started creating the restart point.

Restart points are described at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/wal-configuration.html

A restart point is a point in the transaction history at which a future run of this server could restart without needing to use any write-ahead log file, if the server crashes.  The system creates restarts points periodically, based on how much transaction history happens and the passage of time.

The **log_checkpoints** parameter in the Postgresql configuration file determines whether you get these log messages when the restart points get created.